# iTunes: subscribe to a podcast without downloading it?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I listen to podcasts on iTunes (on OS X 10.11.3 BTW).  There, I said it.  I want to make a list of podcast channels I like so I can find them easily and quickly, but I want to *stream* them, not *download* them.  Apparently if I subscribe to a channel iTunes will try to download stuff -- I do not want this to happen.  If I am not online I will not listen to podcasts.

Any idea on how to achieve this?  I tried and failed, and could not goole an answer.

In case it is not 100% clear, I am using a Mac, not a phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the podcast page in your iTunes Library by selecting it in the menu bar, then click the gear next to the title, then, under "This Computer", select Download Episodes > Off